# SQL Server - Count events that happen from 15 min to 14 days from base time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005. I am trying to count the number of repeats that would fall in between 15 minuites and 14 days when the Client and Type are the same.

The Table [Interactions] looks like:

```
eci_date                 user_ID  Type  Client
2012-05-01 10:29:59.000  user1    12    14
2012-05-01 10:35:04.000  user1    3     15
2012-05-01 10:45:14.000  user3    4     14
2012-05-01 11:50:22.000  user1    5     15
------------------------------------------
2012-05-02 10:30:28.000  user2    12    14
2012-05-02 10:48:59.000  user5    12    14
2012-05-02 10:52:23.000  user2    12    15
2012-05-02 12:49:45.000  user8    3     14
------------------------------------------
2012-05-03 10:30:47.000  user4    5     15
2012-05-03 10:35:00.000  user6    4     12
2012-05-03 10:59:10.000  user7    4     12
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
eci_date    Type  Total_Calls  Total_Repeats
2012-05-01  12    1            2
2012-05-01  3     1            0
2012-05-01  4     1            0
2012-05-01  5     1            1
---------------------------------------------
2012-05-02  12    3            0
2012-05-02  3     1            0
---------------------------------------------
2012-05-03  4     2            1
2012-05-03  5     1            0
```

So there would be 2 repeats because client 14 called in 2 times after the first date they called in because Client and Type must be the same and because I need to filter by day.

Thank You.

Comment: Some ideas to get you started: You can self-join on a date range.  You can use `SUM(Case...` for the conditional counts.

Comment: tried doing a subquery to count them outside of main select statement using a HAVING COUNT(Type) > 1 but i cant figure out how to use the date range that i want. Thanks

Comment: How are you defining a repeat? Do the two rows have to have the same ID and Type value? Is it that the one date is within 14 days of the the second date? Is it that one date is within 15 min of another date? Is it that one date is greater than 15 min away but not 14 days away?

Comment: You need to define your date range better - 15 mins from WHAT?  You list only the date in your desired output - is it from midnight?

Comment: no there is a separate row that i forgot to include (Now added) that has a client number as well. But it will be Client ID and Type Value is what would be a repeat. And im looking for any repeats that occur between 15 min away and 14 days away from the first interaction

Comment: @Brad - *first interaction* is defined how? The first for that Client value? The first for that Client and Type value? The first for any value in the list?

Comment: -1 - We really shouldn't have to interrogate you for 20 minutes just to define the problem.

Comment: I understand the -1. And @Thomas The first interaction is the first time the client calls in. Any following interactions within the 14 day range would count as a repeat.

Comment: @Brad - I see no values in your sample data where for a given Client value, there exists another value more than 15 min away. Thus, AFAICT, your `Total_Repeats` value for the data given should be 0. Can you indicate in your source data which rows should be considered "repeats"?

Comment: @Brad - Are the repeats calculated per day? If not, then why isn't every call from client 14 a repeat after the first call?

Comment: @Brad - In addition, if repeats are calculated per day, then how can there be 4 repeats on 2012-05-01 when there were only 4 calls from two different clients? Wouldn't the maximum number of repeats on this day be 2?

Comment: @Brad - Again, it would be useful if you updated the table to indicate which rows you are considering repeats and why.

Comment: @Brad - Btw, does User_Id enter into the calculation in anyway? As far as I can tell it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With Metrics As
  (
  Select T1.Client, T1.Type
    , Min(eci_Date) As FirstCallDate
  From Table1 As T1
  Group By T1.Client, T1.Type
  )
Select DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d,0,T1.eci_date), 0) As [Day], Type, Count(*) As TotalCalls
  , (
    Select Count(*)
    From Table1 As T2
      Join Metrics As M2
        On M2.Client = T2.Client
          And M2.Type = T2.Type
    Where T2.eci_Date >= DateAdd(mi,15,M2.FirstCallDate)
      And T2.eci_date <= DateAdd(d,15,M2.FirstCallDate)
      And DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d,0,T1.eci_date), 0) = DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d,0,T2.eci_date), 0)
    ) As Total_Repeats
From Table1 As T1
Group By DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d,0,T1.eci_date), 0), Type
Order By [Day] Asc, Type Desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f976/36)

Comment: I understand how this works but sql server 2005 does not have the ability to use DATE like you used in the CAST(eci_date as date). Thank you for all of your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, so I'm interpreting it to mean the following:
* The "total_count" column is the number of distinct users on a given day
* The number of repeats is the number of calls after the first one in the next 14 days

The following query accomplishes this:

```
select eci_date, count(distinct id) as numusers, count(*) as Total_repeats
from 
(
  select cast(eci_date as date) as eci_date, 
     id, 
     count(*) as total,
     min(eci_date) as firstcall
  from table t
  group by cast(eci_date as date), user_id
) t 
left outer join table t2
  on t.user_id = t2.user_id 
  and t2.eci_date between firstcall and dateadd(day, 14, firstcall) 
  and t2.eci_date <> firstcall
group by eci_date
```

Note this uses the syntax `cast(<datetime> as date)` to extract the date portion from a datetime.