# Finding Repeat Call Rate

Tags: sql-server-2005

Im kinda new to SQL Server and am using the 2005 version.

What I need to be able to do is calculate the number of repeat calls that come in.

The table I have called **EP_Call_Int** has columns called "Daily_Dispo_Date" (datetime) , "Login" (nvarchar(35)), "Policy" (int), "Dispo" (Nvarcar(50)) and has data that looks like this:

```
Daily_Dispo_Date     Login    Policy  Dispo
2012-03-01 10:31:54  b_smith  42484   Cancellation
2012-03-01 10:45:12  s_tomas  48424   Payment
2012-03-01 11:01:32  b_smith  41546   Billing Question
2012-03-01 11:04:34  s_tomas  42484   Cancellation
2012-03-01 11:15:42  d_jones  48425   Payment
2012-03-01 11:50:02  d_jones  48425   Billing Question
2012-03-01 13:02:09  b_smith  48425   Billing Question
2012-03-02 10:31:54  d_jones  42489   Payment
2012-03-02 10:45:12  s_tomas  48434   Cancellation
2012-03-02 11:01:32  d_jones  41540   Payment
2012-03-02 11:04:34  s_tomas  41546   Billing Question
2012-03-02 11:15:42  d_jones  48417   Payment
2012-03-02 11:50:02  d_jones  44525   Billing Question
2012-03-02 13:02:09  s_tomas  41546   Billing Question
2012-03-03 10:31:54  d_jones  42089   Cancellation
2012-03-03 10:45:12  s_tomas  48434   Cancellation
2012-03-03 11:01:32  d_jones  41440   Cancellation
2012-03-03 11:04:34  s_tomas  41646   Payment
2012-03-03 11:15:42  d_jones  48817   Payment
2012-03-03 11:50:02  d_jones  41546   Payment
2012-03-03 13:02:09  s_tomas  41446   Payment
```

I have all the test data in a SQL Fiddle Link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0de9c

What im trying to do is count the number of repeat calls our company gets. How I need to count them is by using a time range of 5 minutes to 3 days. So the firstdate will be the first time that person calls in, if they call in again it cant count as a double hit against the same person.

So what im trying to get my final result to look like is:

```
Daily_Dispo_Date    Dispo             Total_Calls   Total_Repeating
2012-03-01          Cancellation      2             1
2012-03-01          Payment           2             0
2012-03-01          Billing Question  3             2
2012-03-02          Payment           3             0
2012-03-02          Cancellation      1             1
2012-03-02          Billing Question  3             2
2012-03-03          Cancellation      3             0
2012-03-03          Payment           3             0
```

The Query I have so far looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME
SET @Start = '20120401'
SET @End = '20120403'
;With [Find_First_Call] As
(
  Select 
     [Policy]
    ,[Dispo]
    ,Min([Daily_Dispo_Date]) As [Call_Date] --need to figure out how to have reset after each call
  From [EP_Call_Int]
  Group By [Policy], [Dispo]
)
Select 
  DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, [Daily_Dispo_Date]), 0) As [Daily_Dispo_Date]
, [Dispo]
, Count([Dispo]) As [Total_Calls]
,(
 Select
   Count([EP_Call_Int2].[Dispo])
 From [EP_Call_Int] as [EP_Call_Int2]
   Left Join [Find_First_Call] as [Find_First_Call] On [Find_First_Call].[Policy] = [EP_Call_Int].[Policy]
   And [Find_First_Call].[Dispo] = [EP_Call_Int].[Dispo]
 Where [EP_Call_Int2].[Daily_Dispo_Date] >= DateAdd(n, 5, [Find_First_Call].[Call_Date])
   And [EP_Call_Int2].[Daily_Dispo_Date] <= DateAdd(dd, 3, [Find_First_Call].[Call_Date])
   And DateAdd(dd, 0, [EP_Call_Int].[Daily_Dispo_Date]), 0) = DateAdd(dd, 0, [EP_Call_Int2].[Daily_Dispo_Date]), 0)
) As [Total_Repeat_Calls]
From [EP_Call_Int]
Where [Daily_Dispo_Date] Between @Start And @End
And [Policy] Like '[4]____'
Group By DateAdd(dd, [Daily_Dispo_Date], 0), [Dispo]
Order By [Daily_Dispo_Date], [Total_Calls] Desc
```

So in short if someone calls in 3 times over the course of 3 days for the same reason it will count as 2 call backs. If they call on day 1, 2, and 3 i need it to show a repeat on day 1 and 2.

Comment: You've made it farther than [this other person who asked pretty much the same question earlier.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10500123/397952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I got all the rules right, but I think this might do it:

```
;with Call_ordinal_no as (
  select 
    convert(date, [Daily_Dispo_Date]) as CallDate,
    [Login],
    [Dispo],
    row_number() over (
      partition by 
        convert(date, [Daily_Dispo_Date]),
        [Login],
        [Dispo]
      order by [Daily_Dispo_Date]
    ) as CallNumber
  from [EP_Call_Int]
)
select 
  CallDate as Daily_Dispo_Date,
  Dispo,
  count(*) as Total_Calls,
  sum(case when CallNumber > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Total_Repeating
from Call_ordinal_no
group by CallDate, Dispo
order by CallDate;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0de9c/34

**Update:**

After discussing the rules in more depth, I think this is the correct SQL:

```
;with calls as (
  select 
    DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, c.[Daily_Dispo_Date]), 0) as CallDate,
    c.[Login],
    c.[Dispo],
    c.[Policy],
    case 
      when first.[Login] is null then 0
      else 1 
    end as IsRepeat
  from [EP_Call_Int] c
  left join [EP_Call_Int] first
    on c.[Login] = first.[Login]
    and c.[Dispo] = first.[Dispo]
    and c.[Policy] = first.[Policy]
    and datediff(minute, first.[Daily_Dispo_Date], c.[Daily_Dispo_Date])
      between 5 and 3 * 24 * 60
)
select 
  CallDate,
  Dispo,
  count(*) as Total_Calls,
  sum(IsRepeat) as Total_Repeating
from calls
group by CallDate, Dispo
order by CallDate, Dispo
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0de9c/69

Comment: I had to change the "convert(date, [Daily_Dispo_Date])" to "DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, [Daily_Dispo_Date]), 0)" to work with SQL 2005. But it is getting the count correctly. The query works great but im not quite sure how to limit the time frame for repeats from the 5 min to 3 days. I think ill have to use "[CallDate] >= DateAdd(mi, 5, [CallDate])" or something like that in a where clause but im not quite sure where to put it. Thank you so much for your help @w0lf

Comment: @Dave Let me understand the rule. Let's consider a scenario with three calls in days 1, 2 and 5. We consider the one in day 1 the first call, the one in day 2 a repeated call (it's within the 3 days limit). What about the call in day 5? Is it also a first call because it's more than 3 days away from day 1?

Comment: The call on day 5 would count as a repeat call on day 2. Each call can only have one repeat (so that it cant count against the same person more than once if they were not at fault). So there would be a repeat call on day 1 and a repeat call on day 2.

Comment: @Dave so all three calls are considered repeats? I don't quite get it. Why is the call on day 1 considered a repeat?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. When a call comes in it is considered the first call. When someone calls in with the same disposition and policy it is considered a repeat if it is within 3 days. When someone calls on Day 1 it is considered the first call. When they call on day 2 it is considered a repeat. When they call in on day 5 it is considered a repeat call for day 2 but day 5 has no repeats yet.

Comment: OK, so we can consider that a "first call" is a call that doesn't have any call (with the same disposition/policy) before it with a time difference between 5 mins and 3 days. All other calls are repeats.

Comment: @Dave Great! Now I managed to understand the rules and I've updated by answer.